# Problem resizing pictures with php

Tags: php

I use the function below to re-size pictures. But I tried it today and it kept giving me an error message that says that the name and path of the picture is not a valid resource although the name and path is quite correct.This is the function:

```
function createthumb($name, $filename, $new_w, $new_h) {
    $system = explode(".", $name);
    if (preg_match("/jpeg|jpg|JPG/", $system[1])) {
        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
    }
    if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1])) {
        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($name);
    }
    $old_x = imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y = imageSY($src_img);
    if ($old_x > $old_y) {
        $thumb_w = $new_w;
        $thumb_h = $old_y * ($new_h / $old_x);
    }
    if ($old_x < $old_y) {
        $thumb_w = $old_x * ($new_w / $old_y);
        $thumb_h = $new_h;
    }
    if ($old_x == $old_y) {
        $thumb_w = $new_w;
        $thumb_h = $new_h;
    }
    $dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $old_x, $old_y);
    if (preg_match("/png/", $system[1])) {
        imagepng($dst_img, $filename);
    } else {
        imagejpeg($dst_img, $filename);
    }
    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
}
```

I used it this way

```
$path = "photos/".$row->pic_name;
createthumb($path, $path, 350, 180);
```

I want it to resize the picture and overwrite the original (source).

The `$row->pic_name` is from the the database and the problem is not from it.
I've been using the function  that way and it works but not this time, maybe I should try a better one?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What error message do you get exactly and in which line?

Comment: Your script have a bug if the filename contains a dot, consider `foo.bar.jpg`. Can you dump the actual filename?

Comment: Check that `$src_img` isn't false after the imagecreatefrom...() calls. As well, what happens if someone uploads some random trash in a file named `haha.pngpong`? Checking file extension isn't a very good method of checking if you've got an image.

Comment: I've tried echoing the file name from the database, i got something like this - 34.jpg, I echoed the variable $path, I got photos/34.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to use `getimagesize()` function, from which you could get `$old_x` (or more appropriately `$old_w`) and `$old_y` (`$old_h`?) and most importantly `IMAGETYPE_XXX` constant which indicates image type. This would rule out 2 possible causes of problems in your code:

1. if file type is capitalised differently, your detection will fail (e.g. `PNG` or `JpG`)
2. as mentioned by alexn if filename contains more dots your script will take a wrong part of the name.

If you prefer to stick with your own way, you could at least do

```
$type = strtolower(array_pop($system));
if ($type == 'jpg' || $type == 'jpeg') {    
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
} elseif ($type == 'png') {
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($name);
}
```

Using RegExps like `/png/` is an overkill here - `strpos(...) !== false` would do the same but much faster. You don't need regular expressions for simple substring search.

And finally, doesn't overwriting an image with its thumb cause you any problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know one simple way. It is ImageMagic

> convert resize